# Typescript error: Property 'status' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've currently got a method that looks like this, which uses `nextjs/auth` to signin with credentials from a form. However, I'm getting a type checking error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

```
const doStuff = async (values: any) => {
    const result: SignInOptions | undefined = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      password: values.pass,
      email: values.email,
    });
    if (result.status === 200 && result.ok) {
      await asyncDispatcher(
        loginUser({
          email: values.email,
          password: values.pass,
        }),
      );
      router.push(props.redirectLocation);
    }
  };
```

I (sortof) understand why, if result == undefined then result.status could potentially be undefined and hey ho ERROR. Fine. So then I try this:

```
const doStuff = async (values: any) => {
    const result: SignInOptions | undefined = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      password: values.pass,
      email: values.email,
    });
    if (result && result.status === 200 && result.ok) {
      await asyncDispatcher(
        loginUser({
          email: values.email,
          password: values.pass,
        }),
      );
      router.push(props.redirectLocation);
    }
  };
```

I then get `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)`  so then I try to implicitly check for the keys `if (result && 'status' in result && result.status === 200 && result.ok) {` but this doesn't work either. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here to get Typescript to play nice?

Under the hood, the definition of signIn (from third party next-auth.js looks like this btw:

```
export declare function signIn<P extends RedirectableProviderType | undefined = undefined>(provider?: LiteralUnion<BuiltInProviderType>, options?: SignInOptions, authorizationParams?: SignInAuthorisationParams): Promise<P extends RedirectableProviderType ? SignInResponse | undefined : undefined>;
```

Update for Googlers.

Wrong Response Type - SignInResponse not SignInOptions

Solution:

```
const result: SignInResponse | undefined = await signIn<'credentials'>('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      password: values.pass,
      email: values.email,
    });
    if (result && 'status' in result && result.status === 200 && result.ok) {
```

Comment: What is your `SignInOptions` type declaration?

Comment: Have you tried to use optional chaining operator on the `if (result?.status === 200 && result?.ok) {`

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck here too. Nothing seemed to make TypeScript happy here fully.

Your updated solution in the original description still gives me: "Property 'ok' does not exist on type 'never'." errors.

This was the only thing that worked for me:

```js
import type {SignInResponse} from 'next-auth/react';
import {signIn} from 'next-auth/react';

const result = await signIn('credentials', {
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    redirect: false,
}) as unknown as SignInResponse;
```

Comment: Combining Abdul's answer, you could pass 'credentials' as the type (`await signIn<'credentials'>`), and then `as unknown` can be removed from the casting.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass in **RedirectableProviderType** 'credentials' as a type

```
    const result: SignInResponse | undefined = await signIn<'credentials'>(
  'credentials',
  {
    redirect: false,
    email: enteredEmail,
    password: enteredPassword,
  }
);

if (!!result && result.error) {
  // set some auth state
  router.replace('/account');
}
```